# How to set multiple environmental variable with Jenkins Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to use Jenkins environmental variable with groovy scripts and assign them to environment variable so I can use those variable through out each Jenkins steps. But I cannot take out Groovy map objects. Is there anything I am doing wrong?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is simple. In groovy script I have added two keys as "repo" and "version". Environment variables are created from that name and in a shell, I can get those simply by calling their keys.

```
echo $repo 
echo $version
```